# Incorrect Float conversion by Argonaut.io

Tags: scala, argonaut

I convert `Float` field of object to json. And value `0.6` converts to `0.6000000238418579` by Argonaut. How to correct it?

Simple test case to check this:

```
import argonaut.Argonaut._
import argonaut.EncodeJson

class Person(val name: Float)
val person = new Person(0.6f)
println("#1")
println(person.name)
def PersonEncodeJson: EncodeJson[Person] =
  EncodeJson((p: Person) => ("name" := p.name) ->: jEmptyObject)
val json = person.asJson(PersonEncodeJson).nospaces
println("#2")
println(json)
```

Console output:

```
#1
0.6
#2
{"name":0.6000000238418579}
```

Comment: How do you know that it's argonaut problem? Are you passing a literal `0.6` that turns into `0.6000000238418579`? Most numbers can not be represented exactly by floating point numbers.

Comment: @Simon I updated the question to give proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have to be using `Float`? Since you care about the exact value, it doesn't seem appropriate.

Example using `BigDecimal` instead:

```
import argonaut.Argonaut._
import argonaut.EncodeJson

class Person(val name: BigDecimal)
val person = new Person(BigDecimal("0.6"))

def PersonEncodeJson: EncodeJson[Person] =
  EncodeJson((p: Person) => ("name" := p.name) ->: jEmptyObject)

person.asJson(PersonEncodeJson).nospaces
// res0: String = {"name":0.6}
```

Or if you can't change the `Person` class, you can convert the `Float` to `String` and then to `BigDecimal`:

```
import argonaut.Argonaut._
import argonaut.EncodeJson

class Person(val name: Float)
val person = new Person(0.6f)

def PersonEncodeJson: EncodeJson[Person] =
  EncodeJson((p: Person) =>
    ("name" := BigDecimal(p.name.toString)) ->: jEmptyObject)

person.asJson(PersonEncodeJson).nospaces
// res0: String = {"name":0.6}
```

Answer (score 2):

That kind of thing is quite normal when handling floats.

```
scala> val a = 0.6f
a: Float = 0.6

scala> val b: Double = a
b: Double = 0.6000000238418579
```

To be sure that it doesn't happen you can format your float before adding to the JSON

```
def PersonEncodeJson: EncodeJson[Person] = EncodeJson((p: Person) => ("name" := "%1.1f" format p.name) ->: jEmptyObject)
```

Comment: That is bad solution, because I need `number` field type in json, not `string`. But you point me that problem is convertion between `Float` and `Double` and now I know the problem that I should explore.

Comment: @Lunigorn Perhaps Chris Martins answer (using BigDecimal) is what you need?